# visual studio 2017 professional - references not resolving (on some machines)

Tags: .net, reference, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

It started with one dev needing to solve some versioning issue. He changes some `System.xxx` references from standard definition now pointing into "packages" folder. We use FW 4.7.1, and this is Web Api project.

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Runtime">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Usually reference like this comes in this form

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
```

**Problem:** yellow warning signs next to references. Looking into property window - no information is found. Project compiles, however. Obviously, against some other DLLs, not ones from `hintPath`. The problem is, even though it compiles, it doesn't copy DLLs into `bin` and app fails to run.

This is something environmental as we have 2 Server 2016 machines where it is working. 1 Win10 as well. But other Win10 machines where it doesn't work.

I thought to use MsBuild to see if that will build properly. But neither MsBuild nor Devenv command lines have not worked. This suggests that issue is more general for the specific OS and VS installations. The reason it compiles is because Devenv and MsBuild are good at walking GAC and then directories until it finds suiting DLL.

Comment: `System.Runtime` is a framework assembly, and the framework assemblies for .NET Framework don't come from packages, so you have 2 references to `System.Runtime`, with different versions. Framework assemblies shouldn't be pulled manually in the project file, they're automatically pulled by the build targets. Do you really need a different version of that framework assembly?

Comment: @JoséPedro Jose, you should research before making such statements. Look here https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/. No, I don't have both. Only package version 4.3.0. I think, this is now part of moving to .net standard. This package -derived system.runtime is good for both, fw4.7.1 and .net core2.0. and it replaces fw-only version. Again, same project works on other machines. I can't understand what mine is missing.

Comment: You might try to use MSBuild diagnostics logging to check how the reference is being resolved at compile time. That might give you more hints, than merely the yellow arrow in VS.

Comment: @T.S., what is your target framework version, .net 4.7.1? and what is your project type? Indeed, there is a bug in 4.7.1 - it shipped with wrong assembly versions, but it still needs a few of these assemblies system.* as spacer. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/567

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT yes 4.7.1. This is web api FW web project. Well, it works on 2 server '16 and 2 win10 machines. One thing I noticed. My VS is 15.6 and machines on which it works are not later than 15.4. So, could be latest update broke it? Tomorrow another "broken guy" will report his VS version. We'll see. Thanks

Comment: @T.S. I think that the `System.Runtime` package was published mainly because of .NET Standard, and the .NET Framework assembly is just an empty assembly with type forwards. .NET Framework 4.7.1 is the first version of .NET Framework which is fully compatible with .NET Standard 2.0, i.e. there's no need to publish .NET Standard facade assemblies, because .NET Standard 2.0 is shipped inbox, so you shouldn't need to install the `System.Runtime` package.

Comment: @JoséPedro Looks like you really did not understand the problem. Certain project types couldn't even get built. But check my updated answer. MS fixed the issue in v15.7 and we're back in business. We just rode on old version of VS/Msbuild on build server while issue existed. Now, we have server updated to a new working version. But on the local boxes devs had issues. And as you see, we made no changes. So, it should prove to you that it was indeed VS issue.

Comment: @LexLi It was just a bug in VS/MsBuild. I updated the answer. I reported it to MS, they fixed it and without any changes to code/projects, we're back to normal.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT You guys fixed it in v15.7. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found what the issue was. This is a bug in VS. I submitted a ticket to VS Dev team and it is now "Under Consideration"

> If I set reference in project file to a packages folder and this reference is "System.[name]" or "Microsoft.[name]", for example "System.Runtime", such reference does not resolve. The project can build but the specific reference is not getting copied into "bin" folder
>
> This started to happen after VS2017 v15.5. Installations v15.2-15.4 resolve references fine.

**The resolution came with VS2017 update7. v15.7 and up resolves this issue**